# How far can a MitM attack go if performed with admin rights on target PC?

Tags: man-in-the-middle

Imagine the scenario :

- attacker has admin access to a machine (being either Windows, macOS or popular Linux system)
- defender is a classic user (not bad nor good)
- objective is to read sensitive data that's normally encrypted over TLS (say stackexchange login)
- not much changes in UI is allowed (for example, the defender won't go on a "suspicious" website if browser tells so)

Comment: How far can it go? ... All the way

Comment: @Maxim Your premise keeps this questions from getting a good answer. I'd postulate, that if an adversary has admin acces to a machine, he/she wouldn't *need* to go through the trouble to set up a MitM attack. You will have to change your constraints to get a more satisfying answer. Something like: "What would the most impactful MitM attack be if the adversary is on the same network as the victim but has no further access to the machine." (Although there's probably a duplicate-looking question somewhere around here)

Answer (score 2):

An attacker that has admin rights can do everything on that machine. The machine is compromised.
A user on this machine cannot do anything to prevent this.

The attacker can change the client executable in any way he likes. Because of this, the transport authentication doesn't help in any way.

Comment: Change the client executable?

Comment: The Admin can do ***everything***, including replacing the browser with one which doesn't care about certificates or logs all your input anyway.

Answer (score -1):

This is a broad question so I will answer it in a broad way. An attacker with admin privileges on the victims computer could allow them to install a new root SSL certificate which is signed and held by the attacker. Now, the victim computer will trust this certificate as if it was distributed by a real trusted authority (i.e. LetsEncrypt).

By doing this, the attacker can launch a MitM attack by pretending to be the server the user is accessing over HTTPS. In other words, the user sends a request for https://google.com. The attacker parses that request, blocks it, contacts Google on the MitM computer, creating an HTTPS connection between Google and the attack compute. Then creates an HTTPS connection between attack and victim computer with the attacker signed (and now rooted) certificate, allowing the attack computer to appear like a safe server on the victim computer. The attack computer then forwards the webpage to victim.

In doing so, attacker can now see and manipulate all data the user sends and receives even though its over HTTPS. Without admin privileges and the ability to install that certificate, the attacker can still do all this but would have seen one of those big certificate not authentic warnings.

Hope it helps!